# Loop in javascript, XML to HTML div will show only the first line

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, rows

I'm a javascript beginner and I can't figure out the loop or loop problem (I don't even know what it's called legally).

Please help me fix the script that loads the data from the XML file.

I borrowed the code to retrieve data from XML.

```
var oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

  function reportStatus() {
    if (oXHR.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) // REQUEST COMPLETED.
      showTheList(this.responseXML); // ALL SET. NOW SHOW XML DATA.
  }

  oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
  oXHR.open("GET", "FILE.xml", true); // true = ASYNCHRONOUS REQUEST (DESIRABLE), false = SYNCHRONOUS REQUEST.
  oXHR.send();  
  
function showTheList(xml) {

  var divBooks = document.getElementById('mtn');  // THE PARENT DIV.
  var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('rows'); // THE XML TAG NAME.

  for (var i = 0; i < Book_List.length; i++) {
  
    // CREATE CHILD DIVS INSIDE THE PARENT DIV.

      var firm_establishment_name = document.createElement('div');
    firm_establishment_name.className = 'col';
    firm_establishment_name.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('firm_establishment_name');

      var order_create_date = document.createElement('div');
    order_create_date.className = 'col';
    order_create_date.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('order_create_date');

      var order_name = document.createElement('div');
    order_name.className = 'col';
    order_name.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('order_name');

      var store_card_code = document.createElement('div');
    store_card_code.className = 'col';
    store_card_code.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('store_card_code');

      var store_card_name = document.createElement('div');
    store_card_name.className = 'col';
    store_card_name.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('store_card_name');

      var quantity = document.createElement('div');
    quantity.className = 'col';
    quantity.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('quantity');

      var delivered_quantity = document.createElement('div');
      delivered_quantity.className = 'col';
    delivered_quantity.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('delivered_quantity');

      var delivery_date = document.createElement('div');
    delivery_date.className = 'col';
    delivery_date.innerHTML = Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute('delivery_date');
    
    // ADD THE CHILD TO THE PARENT DIV.

divBooks.appendChild(firm_establishment_name);
divBooks.appendChild(order_create_date);
divBooks.appendChild(delivery_date);
divBooks.appendChild(order_name);
divBooks.appendChild(store_card_code);
divBooks.appendChild(store_card_name);
divBooks.appendChild(delivered_quantity);
divBooks.appendChild(quantity);

  }
};
```

I prepared the XML, but I always get only the first row and the cycle ends.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<root>
  <export export_date="1.8.2022 15:31:33" export_version="2022_08_01_11_42" export_file_name="FILE.xml"/>
  <rows>
    <row firm_establishment_name="HK" order_create_date="2.2.2022" delivery_date="2.9.2022" order_name="OPE-2071/2022" store_card_code="C28812024H1" store_card_name="Product" quantity="2" delivered_quantity="0"/>
    <row firm_establishment_name="JES" order_create_date="21.3.2022" delivery_date="22.7.2022" order_name="OPE-4928/2022" store_card_code="FGB300-01" store_card_name="Product" quantity="1" delivered_quantity="0"/>
    </rows>
</root>
```

How do I fix this so that I can see all the rows?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('rows'); // THE XML TAG NAME.` You only have one `rows` tag in the xml, so it's only going to iterate once.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem. I would like to ask if it could be fixed so that it repeats inside the rows tag, every single row? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('rows');` You only have one rows tag in the xml, so it's only going to iterate once. I would loop over the row tags themselves, like `var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('row');` OR `var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('rows')[0].children;`

Then, instead of `Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0].getAttribute(...)`, you could just use `Book_List[i].getAttribute(...)` since `Book_List[i]` already refers to the `<row>`. (Also, your original code was only referencing `Book_List[i].getElementsByTagName("row")[0]`, which would only return anything from the first row.)